# User login after Admin approval in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, user

User login after Admin approval in Magento 1.9

Admin need to approve the account before the users can browse the products and view the pricing for the products.

Comment: not clear your requiremnet

Comment: Admin need to approve the account before the users can browse the products and view the pricing for the products

Comment: you need prelogin before anybody access whole website? right?

Comment: yes.. but we use registration and that user approve by the admin then only that user login to the site ..(now in Magento "user registration and login " )  we need to admin approve option ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two requirement :

First admin approval, for this use extension https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

And for second requirement to restrict user to login before browsing website, for this you have to create a custom module or can edit in existing custom module for this:

add event in config.xml :

```
...
<events>
    <controller_action_predispatch>
        <observers>
            <restrictcustomers_controller_action_predispatch>
                <class>Custom_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>restrictCustomer</method>
            </restrictcustomers_controller_action_predispatch>
        </observers>
    </controller_action_predispatch>
</events>
...
```

In `Model/Observer.php` :

```
public function restrictCustomer(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $action = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getActionName());
    $controller = strtolower(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getControllerName());
    $openActions = array(
        'index',
        'create',
        'createpost',
        'login',
        'loginpost',
        'logoutsuccess',
        'forgotpassword',
        'forgotpasswordpost',
        'resetpassword',
        'resetpasswordpost',
        'confirm',
        'confirmation'
    );          

    if (($controller == 'customer_account' || $controller == 'account') && in_array($action, $openActions)) {
        return; //if in allowed actions do nothing.
    }

    if ($controller == 'index' && $action == 'loginpost') 
    {
        return; //if in allowed actions do nothing.
    }

    if(! Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()){
        Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getResponse()->setRedirect(Mage::getUrl('customer/account/login'));
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see this:

[How to add a customer pre-approval module?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61042/how-to-add-a-customer-pre-approval-module)

https://www.extensionhut.com/customer-approve-disapprove.html

http://www.magebright.com/magento-customer-approve-extension.html#

Hope this can help you.

Comment: ok. thx.. we try it..

Answer (score 0):

By default, Customer approval functionality is not available in magento. You can use the community extension for customer approval functionality.

Here is one community extension available for this: https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation

Comment: ok. thx.. we try it..

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on boolean in /home/xxxxx/public_html/xxxx/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463  (error )

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is not available with Magento by default. So you probably need to implement this using a module. Basically, what you need to do here is:

1. Create a customer attribute `status` for the customer entity.
2. Now disable users activity when the status is **inactive**. This can involve disable users from viewing the catalog, disable the user from doing checkout, etc.

Hence this is too broad to answer in a single answer. You can also look for some nice extension that does the same functionality. I recommend [this extension](https://github.com/Vinai/customer-activation).

I hope you can deal with this.